# Should we distinugish integers, floats and doubles from NUMBER in lexer?

Tags: compiler-construction

In compile design, do people recommend to make a general token class named "NUMBER" instead of defining integers, floats and doubles? Should I wait until later to figure out?

Comment: In most lexers/parsers I've seen, the lexer distinguishes between integer and floating point literals, but I guess you could postpone that determination until semantic analysis, if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

As with most such questions, the only possible answer is "it depends". But on the whole, unless you are doing direct calculator-style interpretation in a one-pass parser, using more than one numeric token type is unnecessary, since it will only serve to complicate the grammar.

There are lots of scripting languages which only have one type of number (`awk`, for example), so all numeric tokens are converted to double-precision floating point in the lexer and there is no need for additional token types at all.

A lexer for C/C++ needs to be able to recognize "preprocessing numbers", a set which includes integer and floating point literals in a variety of formats, and a lot of strings which are not valid numbers at all ("42itous", for example), but does not include character or boolean constants. These need to be resolved (or rejected) once preprocessing is complete; after that, it's not really necessary for any grammatical purpose to distinguish between different numerical types, although it will eventually be necessary for code generation.

So it wouldn't be surprising for the relexer (i.e., the post-preprocessing lexical analyzer) to produce a token type of "constant" whose semantic value included more detailed type information.

In a typical expression grammar, you will either have a `CONSTANT` token type whose semantic value is a variant including the constant's actual type and value, or you will have a `constant` nonterminal whose productions are a list of different token types with corresponding actions which fill in a variant semantic value with the constant's actual type and value. Clearly, there is not much difference between these strategies; personally, I'd almost always go for the lexer solution but that's just me.

It's often tempting to insist that things like array declarations include only integer literals for dimensions, forcing the grammar to distinguish between integer literal tokens and other literal tokens. But the grammar is not always the best place to produce error messages for errors like this; it might be *much* simpler to generate a meaningful error message during semantic analysis.